# Nav bar link positions aren't centered under image

Tags: html, css

I'm a very new programmer working on a product landing project for FCC and am currently stuck trying to align the nav links under a logo image. Some bits of the css are messy or blank because I've been experimenting.

I've tried different margins, flex-directions, and padding.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header-img {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 75rem;
  width: 45rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 7.5rem;
  padding: 0rem 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: ;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 5rem;
}

nav>ul {
  width: 35vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header id="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img id="header-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/G5nVsYG.png" alt="ar-15 logo" />
    </div>

    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#points">What seperates us</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#put-together">How to build</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#product-price">Current Product Deals</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

I expected the nav links to be under the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add to header tag 'flex-wrap: wrap;'

I added what I wrote in the title and it lowered the NAV.

By the way, in CSS you should use Class.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header-img {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 75rem;
    width: 45rem;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 7.5rem;
    padding: 0rem 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: ;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 5rem;
}

nav > ul {
/*     width: 35vw; */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
} 
nav ul li {
padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<header id="header">
        <div class="logo">  
            <img id="header-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/G5nVsYG.png" alt="ar-15 logo" />            
        </div>    

        <nav id="nav-bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#points">What seperates us</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#put-together">How to build</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#product-price">Current Product Deals</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```